# Not able to see ngBootstrap design's progress bar. - Angular 4+

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

i can't find what i had miss. am not able view @ngbootstrap progress bar. there is no error in console.

trying to replicating [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rnokxlymqld?file=app%2Fprogressbar-showvalue.ts)

### progressBar.html

```
<div class="container">
<!--<ngbd-progressbar-showvalue></ngbd-progressbar-showvalue>-->

<p><ngb-progressbar showValue="true" type="success" [value]="25"></ngb-progressbar></p>
<p><ngb-progressbar [showValue]="true" type="info" [value]="50"></ngb-progressbar></p>
<p><ngb-progressbar showValue="true" type="warning" [value]="150" [max]="200"></ngb-progressbar></p>
<p><ngb-progressbar [showValue]="true" type="danger" [value]="150" [max]="150"></ngb-progressbar></p>
</div>
```

### module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  imports: [NgbModule],
  declarations: [firstComponent, secondComponent,thirdComponent,progressComponent,
})
```

### progressComponent.ts

```
@Component(
{
    selector: 'ngbd-progressbar-showvalue',
    // template:'<p><ngb-progressbar  showValue= "true" type="success" [value]="25"></ngb-progressbar></p>'
    /*<p><ngb-progressbar [showValue]= "true" type="info"    [value]="50"></ngb-progressbar></p>
      <p><ngb-progressbar showValue= "true"  type="warning" [value]="150"" [max]="200"></ngb-progressbar></p>'
     */
    // ,
    templateUrl: './skills.component.html',
    /*styleUrls: ['./skills.component.scss']*/
    styles: [`
ngb-progressbar {
margin-top: 5rem;
}
`]
})
```

but its simple showing values like below attachment without progress bar [image].

cli version

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 9.3.0
OS: win32 ia32
Angular: 6.0.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      6.3.2
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/material                 6.3.2
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

thanks for helping me

Comment: First of all, you need at least Angular 6.1.0, not just 4+, for the latest version of ng-bootstrap. Second, it seems you simply forgot to add the bootstrap CSS to your application.

Comment: @JBNizet  actually , mine is angular 6 only. i just mention it as 4, so that my question will be reachable to every one. 

could you pls elaborate this "forgot to add the bootstrap CSS " , where to add?

Comment: There are several ways. One would be to rely on a CDN (see the index.html file in the stackblitz you linked to). Another would be to install it in the app, as described here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap.

Comment: how fool i am..? as you said cdn did the magic. now its working.. could you pls tell me, is that right way to add cdn in index.html? is that good practice ?

Comment: It has advantages and disadvantages. You can't customize the CSS (SCSS variables, included parts, etc.). If you test your app locally, you'll still need the network to download the CSS. If the CDN is down or compromised (which is unlikely), your app doesn't work anymore. The advantage is that a user of your app might already have the CSS it in his browser cache if he visited another web site using the same CDN URL as yours. And of course you don't pay for the bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Add below link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

in your **index.html** file. This is required for the CSS to work.
It will be much better practice, if you can download the file, keep that file in your assets folder and add the link to the file inside your index.html like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

by this way your project will be unaffected, by if any change is done in the *bootstrap.min.css* parent link.

Comment: yup i saw the comments just now. Still i am keeping the answer for any future coder, if they face similar issue.